# Getting external storage path doesn't work in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, storage, external

I have written an android code to take a photo (using the android camera app). I want to save this photo in the external storage, so I'm using the Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) to get the directory path.

This is my code:

```
public void takePhoto(View b){
    /** Esta función recoge la pulsación del botón de tomar fotografía.
     *  Se encarga de lanzar la cámara de fotos del móvil y permitir al 
     *  usario hacer una fotografía.
     *  
     *  Se comprueba si se puede almacenar la foto, para después enviarla
     *  al backend. Si no, no se permite hacer la foto.
     */
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Se crea un File con el path donde se quiere almacenar la foto
        fileName = new String("Incidencia_"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())+".jpg");
        storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/SmartRoutes", fileName);
        //storageDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/SmartRoutes", fileName);
        if(storageDir != null)
            Log.d(logTag, "Path: "+storageDir.toString());
        // y se pasa al intent como extra.
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(storageDir));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No es posible sacar una fotografía", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then on the onActivityResult(), I try to get the photo stored in "storageDir" and simply print the path in LogCat:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /** En esta función se recogen los resultados de las activities lanzadas desde esta.
     *  En este caso la de la cámara de fotos.
     */
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Foto tomada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Se añade la foto a la galería
            //Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            //photoFile = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
            photoFile = storageDir;
            Toast.makeText(this, "File.toString(): "+photoFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Foto cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The thing is that I've tested this code in a Samsung Nexus S device with Android 4.0.1 and in a Samsung Galaxy Mini with Android 2.3.6 and it worked perfectly. But when I try to test the code in a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Samsung Glaxy Note 2, both with Android 4.1.1 the line

```
storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/SmartRoutes", fileName);
```

returns always null, so storageDir = null, I have no idea why.

Can it be something about Android version 4.1.1?

Comment: ... something wrong in your question. storageDir = new File(...) so it CANNOT BE NULL.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question, but you do have an external sd card in the S3 and Note 2 correct?

Answer (score 1):

To get root derictory on your SD card you can use:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

instead of

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) // Folder which used by camera/gallery app.
```

Try also add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `SmartRoutes` directory does not exist. Try adding `mkdirs` after setting the `storageDir`. So it would be:

```
storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/SmartRoutes", fileName);
storageDir.mkdirs();
```